# Finding memory leaks in a C++ application with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, valgrind

In Linux, I have been using valgrind for checking if there are memory leaks in an application. What is the equivalent in Windows? Can this be done with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Answer (score 94):

Visual Studio 2019 has a decent memory analysis tool, it may be used interactively while debugging or by programming (without debugging), I show a minimal example in both cases in the following.

The main idea is to take a snapshot of the heap at the beginning and at the end of the process, then to compare the states of memory to detect potential memory leaks.

### Interactively

Create the following `main.cpp` file (in a new console application) :

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
 int a = 1;
 char* s = new char[17];
 strcpy_s(s,17,"stackoverflow_pb");
 char* ss = new char[14];
 strcpy_s(ss, 14,"stackoverflow");
 delete[] ss;
 return 0;
}
```

Then :

1. Put a breakpoint on the first line "int a..."
2. Click Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools; and pick memory usage
3. Then debug the code (<kbd>F5</kbd>), when the breakpoint is hit, click `Take snapshot` on the Memory Usage summary toolbar.
4. Go to the last line "return 0.." (`step over` (<kbd>F10</kbd>) several times) and take another snapshot.
5. Click on the red arrow in the second snapshot (in memory usage tab)
6. this will open a new "snapshot" tab that permits you to compare this snapshot with the first one (or another one) and to detect memory leaks. In this example there is a memory leak for variable  `s` (stackoverflow_pb). You can find it by double click the "char[]" object.

The key steps of the above procedure are shown in the following image:

[image: memory analysis interactively]

### By programming

Replace the code with the following:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "windows.h"
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC //to get more details
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>   //for malloc and free
int main()
{
    _CrtMemState sOld;
    _CrtMemState sNew;
    _CrtMemState sDiff;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&sOld); //take a snapshot
    char* s = new char[17];
    strcpy_s(s, 17, "stackoverflow_pb");
    char* ss = new char[14];
    strcpy_s(ss, 14, "stackoverflow");
    delete[] ss;
    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&sNew); //take a snapshot 
    if (_CrtMemDifference(&sDiff, &sOld, &sNew)) // if there is a difference
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"-----------_CrtMemDumpStatistics ---------");
        _CrtMemDumpStatistics(&sDiff);
        OutputDebugString(L"-----------_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince ---------");
        _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince(&sOld);
        OutputDebugString(L"-----------_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks ---------");
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It does the same thing but by code, so you can integrate it in an automatic build system, the functions [`_CrtMemCheckpoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtmemcheckpoint?view=vs-2019) take the snapshots and [`_CrtMemDifference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtmemdifference?view=vs-2019) compare the memory states of snapshot and returns true is they are different.

Since it is the case, it enters the conditional block and prints details about the leaks via several functions (see [_CrtMemDumpStatistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtmemdumpstatistics?view=vs-2019) , [_CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtmemdumpallobjectssince?view=vs-2019) and [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtdumpmemoryleaks?view=msvc-160) - the latter doesn't require snapshots).

To see the output, put a break point in the last line "return 0", hit `F5` and look at the debug console. Here is the output :

[image]

---

To get more information, see the following links :

- Interactive analysis : [Measure memory usage in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019)
- via programming : [Find memory leaks with the CRT library](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [CRT debug Heap Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2019) (for heap corruption also)

Comment: This is very good. Is there a way we can check for 1. mixing array `new[]` and the wrong `delete`, 2. accessing freed memory, 3. other ways of corrupting memory like out of bound access and such. 4. Accessing uninitialized memory

Comment: Sorry I don't know for 1,3 and 4 but I would use a static analysis tool for it. Regarding 2 (accessing freed memory) you can use the `_CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF` flag (see the above link "CRT debug Heap Files").

Comment: Thanks. `OutputDebugStringW` required for `LPCWSTR`, (3 characters not enough for an edit as the rest of the answer is perfect!)

Comment: `/fsanitize=address` can now be used with x64 and x86 for similar memory problems. [AddressSanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-160#:~:text=Use%20the%20AddressSanitizer%20in%20Visual%20Studio,-AddressSanitizer%20is%20integrated&text=In%20the%20Property%20Pages%20dialog,OK%20to%20save%20your%20changes.)

Comment: This is 1000% too much work. Is there really no Windows valgrind equivalent?

Comment: @Roflcopter4 not really. Your best bet might be to develop on Linux with Valgrind and make sure it's portable enough to also compile on Windows.

Comment: Came here because `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` isn't giving me file/line info (VS 2019) as indicated in the help pages. I unfortunately see the same issue in the screenshot above.

Comment: @LaurieStearn does AddressSanitizer works in VS2010 ultimate (windows)?

Comment: @Zm_dev: Ayxan Haqverdili is sure to know the answer. (cannot ref more than user in comment, sorry).

Comment: if I were to use the programming method, but wanted to see the results in the output debug window.. is it fine if I just run the program as normal for a while (minutes, hours) then attach to it and quit the program while attached? the dump info should then be for the entire time the program was running? or just while it was attached?

Comment: This only works if you know there is a leak in the first place and is actively looking for it. I know you can use _CrtSetDbgFlag(...) but I wish there is just a toggle button in Visual Studio instead of needing to pasting _CrtXYZ(...) call in every time.

Comment: This won't work if you run in Release mode :(

Answer (score 13):

How about [Visual Leak Detector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/visualleakdetector.aspx)? It's not inbuild, but I do think it's the most popular one.

Comment: Has since moved to https://kinddragon.github.io/vld/, and then was apparently abandoned in 2017.

Comment: Still seems to work with VS 2019, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58439722/how-to-install-visual-leak-detector-on-visual-studio-2019

Answer (score 4):

[C++ Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-memory.php) finds memory and handle leaks in native Windows programs built with Visual Studio, Delphi and other compilers. Fast and can handle large workloads (some users track several billion allocations and deallocations in one run).

Disclosure: I'm the designer of C++ Memory Validator. We built it because other tools couldn't handle the workload when we were working with SolidWorks R&D Ltd.

Answer (score 4):

[Dr. Memory](http://drmemory.org/) is a memory monitoring tool capable of identifying memory-related programming errors such as accesses of uninitialized memory, accesses to unaddressable memory (including outside of allocated heap units and heap underflow and overflow), accesses to freed memory, double frees, memory leaks, and (on Windows) handle leaks, GDI API usage errors, and accesses to un-reserved thread local storage slots.

Dr. Memory operates on unmodified application binaries running on Windows, Linux, Mac, or Android on commodity IA-32, AMD64, and ARM hardware.

Dr. Memory is built on the [DynamoRIO](http://dynamorio.org/) dynamic instrumentation tool platform.

Comment: Following the instructions on the page, I get "Dr.Memory internal crash" Any suggestions?

Comment: DrM is great when if works,but like others are finding, the Feb 2020 2.3.0.1 is prone to having internal segfaults.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2015 and later versions have Native Memory Leak Diagnostic Tool, check this for details: https://dzone.com/articles/native-memory-leak-diagnostics.

Comment: Is this feature available in the Community edition as well?

Comment: It's available in my VS 2017 Community Edition, not sure about 2015.

Answer (score 3):

[Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-risk-detection/concepts/application-verifier) is a good tool for detecting leaks in native (C or C++) application. You can use it along with Visual studio or WinDbg . Apart from memory leaks, you can check for heap corruptions, invalid handle usage as well. Using application verifier along with WinDbg (!analyze -v) provides good insights.

Answer (score 1):

A reliable solution is to use the [Address Sanitizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-160) for visual studio. This is a cross platform / cross compiler solution so the knowledge you gain will be transferable to [gcc and clang](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

This tool has extensions for thread sanitization, and general memory error detection (use after free, double free, uninitialized use etc) but leak detection is one of its strong points. You need the `/fsanitize=address /Zi` options for the Microsoft compiler, but you can refer on the first linked article on how to incorporate it on solutions and bigger projects (either through CMake configurations, or project properties tweaking)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DevPartner tool for finding memory leaks in C++ applications using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

A standalone tool (CLI) for tracking native (C++) memory leaks. Run your app in Release mode (PDBs should be available) and let it run along with it. It outputs all the suspected call stacks and their respected leak size:

[GitHub: C++ Memory Leak Detector for Windows](https://github.com/avipreshel/NativeMemoryLeakDetection)