# memory usage keep increasing as the C++ program running

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, sdl

i made a program to move a dot around on the screen. i was basically just recreating lazyfoo sdl tutorial.
the problem is my program eats memory. its memory usage is slowly increasing at like 200kb/s rate. it grows bigger overtime.

i tested it using visual leak detector, it says no memory leak.
so what did i do wrong??
please help me. it's driving me crazy.

here is the code: credit to lazyfoo.
if the code is too long or unclear i will edit it as necessary.
thank you.

```
//Main Stage
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (!init())
    {
        printf("failed to init! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        cTile *tileSet[TOTAL_TILES];

        if (!loadMedia(tileSet))
        {
            printf("failed to load media! \n");
        }
        else
        {
            bool running = true;
            SDL_Rect wall;
            wall.x = 200;
            wall.y = 200;
            wall.h = 150;
            wall.w = 70;
            cDot Dot1(1270, 720);
            cDot Dot2(SCREEN_HEIGHT / 4, SCREEN_WIDTH / 4);
            cTimer timer;
            SDL_Event e;
            SDL_Color textColor = { 0, 0, 120, 120 };

            std::vector<SDL_Rect> camera;
            camera.resize(1);
            camera[0] = { 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT };

            Uint32 startTime = 0;
            std::stringstream timeText;
            int countedFrames = 0;
            timer.start();

            while (running)
            {
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
                {
                    if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                    {
                        running = false;
                    }

                    Dot1.handleEvent(e);

                    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_BUTTONS; i++)
                    {
                        buttons[i].buttonEvent(&e);
                    }
                }

                float avgFPS = countedFrames / (timer.getTicks() / 1000.f);
                if (avgFPS > 2000)
                {
                    avgFPS = 0;
                }

                if (!textTexture.loadTextFromFile(timeText.str().c_str(), textColor))
                {
                    printf("unable to render text ypoooooo");
                }

                timeText.str("");
                timeText << "fps " << avgFPS;

                Dot1.move(tileSet);
                Dot1.setCamera(camera[0]);

                /*camera.x = (Dot1.getPosX() + cDot::DOT_WIDTH / 2) - SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
                camera.y = (Dot1.getPosY() + cDot::DOT_HEIGHT / 2) - SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;*/

                /*if (camera.x < 0){ camera.x = 0; }
                if (camera.y < 0){ camera.y = 0; }
                if (camera.x > LEVEL_WIDTH - camera.w){ camera.x = LEVEL_WIDTH - camera.w; }
                if (camera.y > LEVEL_HEIGHT - camera.h){ camera.y = LEVEL_HEIGHT - camera.h; }*/

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

                //SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
                //SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &wall);
                for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TILES; ++i)
                {
                    tileSet[i]->render(camera);
                }
                //BGTexture.render(0, 0, &camera);
                Dot1.render(camera[0]);

                textTexture.render(250, 250);
                timeTextTexture.render(250, 250 + textTexture.getWidth());
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    //buttons[i].render();
                }


                //Dot2.render(camera.x, camera.y);

                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
                if (timer.started())
                {
                    countedFrames++;
                }
                else if (!timer.started())
                {
                    countedFrames = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        close(tileSet);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

solution is so simple THANKS TO PAUL AND WEATHER VANE !!!! apparently i put these lines of code inside a loop. where its main function is basically creating texture. and it loads texture over and over again because it's inside a loop. i just need to delete it.
these lines:

```
if (!textTexture.loadTextFromFile(timeText.str().c_str(), textColor))
                    {
                        printf("unable to render text ypoooooo");
                    }
```

THANK YOU GUYS!!! :)
sorry i can't vote up, apparently it needs more reputation to vote an answer up. :|

Comment: Things not on my to-do list today: Dig through 1000 lines of code to find someone's memory leaks.

Comment: Show where the allocations take place

Comment: I think you need to identify what else you've done except run a memory profiler. In other words, identify places where you think you might have your issue. It probably has to do with allocating memory, but not freeing it, pointers to nothing, etc. Identify those spots in your code, unless you don't know how to figure that out at all.

Comment: yeah, it seems that making someone dig through my code is too much. my bad. i'm sorry guys. i'll just delete my question. and thank you.

Comment: @user3189174 Something like valgrind may come in handy.

Comment: i use windows, valgrind runs on linux right?

Comment: @user3189174 Depends on your actual toolchain. With MSVC there are the [MS tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790564/finding-memory-leak-of-c-application-in-visual-studio), for others you might want to use [valgrind for windows](http://sourceforge.net/p/valgrind4win/wiki/DevelopmentEnvironment/)

Comment: Just a comment, but why the raw pointers?  Have you considered a unique_ptr or shared_ptr so you don't have to go through this.

Comment: honestly, i'm fairly new to c++, i made this program 2 days ago. and still learning how pointer works. and apparently the tutorial is using raw pointers. i'll read some more about unique and shared pointers. thank you.

Comment: @user3189174 Concentrate on your `main()` function.  What calls are you making that obviously allocate memory, whether you're doing it explicitly, or calling an `SDL_` function?  You have a while() loop going, and very few of those functions actually do anything w.r.t memory allocation.  It shouldn't be that difficult to pinpoint *where* the error occurs, even if you don't know *how* to fix the error.

Comment: @user3189174 In addition, since your classes do not follow the "rule of 3", please add unimplemented, user-defined copy constructor and assignment op (or if using C++ 11, `delete` them).  This ensures that you're not copying your objects, thus causing a memory leak to potentially occur.

Comment: THANK YOU PAULMCKENZIE!!! i found it because of you. thank you so much!!! i'm happy. :D

Comment: Ah yeah.  The general guideline is use smart pointers where you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this which only deletes when NULL.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TILES; ++i)
{
    if (tiles[i] == NULL)
    {
        delete tiles[i];
        tiles[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is another shot: you call `loadTextFromFile()` in your main loop repetition, but only call `SDL_DestroyTexture()` in the final `close()`.

And here is a similar question, [Memory leak SDL while using SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24938695/memory-leak-sdl-while-using-sdl-createtexturefromsurface)

Comment: That's a heroic deed!

Comment: i've changed it too check if it's not NULL, doesn't help. beside that, it's only active when i close the program. thank you by the way

Comment: @user3189174 - You shouldn't need to check for NULL / not NULL  anyway.  It is perfectly legal and safe to delete a null pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Though, as the OP applied this condition it obviously should be `if (tiles[i] != NULL)` instead, no?

Comment: i've deleted the NULL checker now.

Comment: @user3189174 I've added another "possible" to my answer.

Comment: thank you. i didn't read this earlier. but i've found it!!! thank you