# How to validate memory correctness with VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, valgrind, software-quality

Memory correctness means

- use after free
- leaks
- use of uninitialized memory
- memory corruption

Other platforms have tools such as Valgrind or the address sanitizer.

Please note that I don't want to run my Windows binaries on Linux with Wine so that I might be able to use Valgrind. I would prefer a solution that fits a VisualStudio focused shop.

How do I do this on Windows in a VisualStudio environment?

Comment: Or [Finding memory leaks in a C++ application with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790564/finding-memory-leaks-in-a-c-application-with-visual-studio)

Comment: Both questions are not really helpful to me. One is only addressing a subset of my question (leaks), while the second has two commercial tools as accepted answer - both of which I have prior experience with (which was not good).

Comment: Is there something directly in one of the VisualStudio product variants which would fullfil these requirements?